# How to make the 'All pages' as the Main Page in Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I have set up a media wiki on our dev server for our developers to use. I hope to see it as a repository of random nuggets of information and research that various people have done.

The Main page of Media Wiki isn't really that useful, as the default front page. Is it possible to make the 'All pages' special page as the default page of the wiki?

What I mean by that is that whenever visits the wiki, without specifying a specific page, they should see the 'All pages' special page instead of the 'Main Page' .

Comment: This is probably better suited for the [Webmasters SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) as it's about help with your own website, not a Web App.

Comment: @AndrewLott: If the mods think this question belongs on Webmasters.SE, I would not mind it being migrated there. I posted the question here, since there are 69 questions tagged media-wiki here, and only 56 question with that tag on webmasters.se.

Comment: The problem is that Media Wiki is a self-hosted solution, so by definition should be off-topic here. It's likely that those other questions need to be closed too.

Comment: @AlEverett - self hosting is irrelevant if the question is about the **usage** of media wiki rather than the installation. I'd say this is on topic.

Comment: @ChrisF: Fair enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can transclude Special:AllPages: `{{Special:AllPages}}`. On my tiny testing wiki, that displays a table with all pages on the wiki.

Comment: Maybe by brain has gone for a holiday or something, but I cannot understand what you mean by: "You can transclude Special:AllPages: {{Special:AllPages}}"

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Just write the code `{{Special:AllPages}}` into your main page, just as if Special:AllPages was a template you were [transcluding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Transclusion).

Comment: Awsome! With your link, and this FAQ: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:FAQ#How_do_I_change_which_page_is_the_main_page.3F I could change the page. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can change the contents of "MediaWiki:Mainpage" to contain the text "Special:AllPages". Whenever users click on the "Main page" link on the sidebar, the logo or accessing your wiki's domain name, you will be immediately directed to the special page.

The advantage of this is that they see "All pages" as the page title and not "Main Page".

Comment: A disadvantage of this is that you can't have anything else on the main page then. If you use transclusion instead, you can have some welcome text there, or something like that, in addition to the list of all pages.

Comment: @svick Yep, that is true, though in my opinion transcluding a special page sometimes suck.